# When keeping bandwidth usage low is more important than performance, is it worth it to use binary serialization over JSON?

Tags: json, serialization, binary

I have a server talking to a mobile app, and this app potentially does thousands of requests per day. I don't care that much about performance in this particular case, so saving some miliseconds isn't as big as a concern as saving bandwidth - especially since I'm paying for it.

(1) What is the advantage of using JSON over binary here, when bandwidth is a much bigger deal than performance? I mean, I have read some people saying that the size difference between raw data and JSON isn't really that much - and that might as well be partially true, but when you have thousands of daily requests being made by hundreds of thousands of users, merely doubling the amount of bytes will have a huge impact on bandwidth usage - and in the end, on the server bill.

Also, some people said that you can easily alter the JSON output format, while changing the binary serialization might be a little more complicated. Again, I agree, but shouldn't it be a little more complicated than that? Like, what are the odds that we're gonna change our format? Will the ease of change make up for JSON's bandwidth excess?

(2) And finally, I stumbled upon [this link](https://maxondev.com/serialization-performance-comparison-c-net-formats-frameworks-xmldatacontractserializer-xmlserializer-binaryformatter-json-newtonsoft-servicestack-text/) while doing some research on this topic, and in the summary table (Ctrl + F, 'summary') it says that the JSON data size is smaller than the actual binary data? How is that even possible?

I would very much appreciate some answers to these questions.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> thousands of requests per day

that's ... not really a lot, so most approaches will usually be fine

> What is the advantage of using JSON over binary here, when bandwidth is a much bigger deal than performance?

JSON wouldn't usually *have* an advantage; usually that would go to binary protocols - things like protobuf; however, *compression* may be more significant than choice of protocol. If you want meaningful answers, however, the only way to get that is to test it with **your** data.

If bandwidth is your key concern, I'd go with protobuf, adding compression on top if you have a lot of text data in your content (text compresses beautifully, and protobuf simply uses UTF8, so it is still available for compression).

> it says that the JSON data size is smaller than the actual binary data?

JSON contains textual field names, punctuation (`"`, `:`, `,`), etc - and all values are textual rather than primitive; JSON will be larger than *good* binary serializers. The article, however, compares to `BinaryFormatter`; `BinaryFormatter` does *not* qualify as a good binary serializer IMO. It is *easy to use* and works without needing to do anything. If you compare against something like protobuf: protobuf will beat JSON *every* time. And sure enough, if we look at the table: JSON is 102 or 86 bytes (depending on the serializer); protobuf-net is 62 bytes, MsgPack is 61, `BinaryFormatter` is 669. Do not conflate "a binary serializer" with `BinaryFormatter`. I blame the article for this error, not you.  MsgPack and Protocol Buffers (protobuf-net) are binary serializers, and they come out in the lead.

(disclosure: I'm the author of protobuf-net)

Comment: Marc, thank you very much for your answer. However, I think I didn't express myself well on the requests part: I have thousands of request per day, being made by _each_ of the hundreds of thousands of users - with the potential to reach millions of users some day. We are talking about hundreds of millions (and potentially billions) of requests daily. Isn't that a lot? (this is a genuine question, it's not my intention to be snide or anything like that)

Comment: @ogabrielp oh, indeed that changes things a lot; I'd be optimizing that all the way :)